# How to find out the set login timeout for a Connection object in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have a Connection object in Java(1.5) and I want to know what value was set for the login timeout.  Is there a way to access this?

I am trying to set the timeout in the URL itself, like jdbc:server//host....etc..;loginTimeout=5 and I am basically trying to confirm that it has taken effect

Comment: What do you even mean by login timeout?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What happens during the login? To what are you connecting and how are you making the connection(s)?

Comment: I don't think the timeout is defined on the `Connection` object itself, but instead on whatever is acquiring the connection (see [DriverManager#getLoginTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getLoginTimeout%28%29)).

Answer (score 2):

Use [DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)  class to set up database server login connection timeout.

```
// Getting timeout value
int timeout = DriverManager.getLoginTimeout();

// Setting timeout value
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(timeout)
```

Comment: This is for saving the timeout if I am not mistaken. Not retrieving it

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get the LoginTimeout of the DriverManager is directly from DriverManager using:

```
int timeout = DriverManager.getLoginTimeout();
```